# wxMaxima Change equal sign (=) into a string (-->)

Tags: string, operator-keyword, maxima

I have the following wxMaxima code:

/* [wxMaxima: input   start ] */

one:2*H[2];

/* [wxMaxima: input   end   ] */

/* [wxMaxima: input   start ] */

two:O[2];

/* [wxMaxima: input   end   ] */

/* [wxMaxima: input   start ] */

three:2*H[2]*O;

/* [wxMaxima: input   end   ] */

/* [wxMaxima: input   start ] */

one+two = three;

/* [wxMaxima: input   end   ] */

and I would like to change the equal sign (=) with the arrow (-->).
Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `infix("-->");` and then you can input `foo + bar --> baz` directly (no need to write it first with `=` and then substitute `-->` for `=`).

Comment: Almost solved. How to avoid the parentheses that now from foo + bar --> baz in many cases I get (foo + bar) --> (baz).

Comment: Try `infix("-->", 80, 80)` instead. That makes `-->` the same operator precedence as `=` (otherwise, by default, the new operator is assigned a high precedence). Does that make the parentheses go away?